# PyCharm IDE Python Console: execute multiple-line command without hitting *enter* on last position

Tags: python, pycharm

Is the a shortcut to execute multiple lines of code, without having to move the cursor to the last line? For example after changing something in the middle of the code block and not wanting to use the arrows-key to go to the end.

Comment: What do you mean by "move the cursor to the last line"? Are you, perhaps, using IDLE? You cannot normally "change something in the middle of the code block" in the command-line interpreter (`python.exe`); pressing the up arrow doesn't move the cursor to a previous line, but instead (typically) replicates a previous line on the current one.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I am using the PyCharm IDE. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press `ctrl+end` to go to the end of the python multiline script, and then hit `enter` (if you are in an indentation block such as editing a for loop, first delete the indentation with `backspace`, then `enter`). A more specific shortcut for that operation would be too much of a whim, nobody would need it.